# Calculate achievable points for vehicle with turning circle

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to determine the set of achievable positions for a vehicle that can travel a fixed distance.

In the following diagram the blue marker is the vehicle, and the pink shape is the set of achievable positions.

I know the turning circle radius and the maximum distance that can be travelled.

From looking at the problem the "travel distance" is the distance from the origin the point directly ahead on the curve.   It is also the distance along the circumference of the curve.

But, I cannot think of the maths to determine the shape of the outer edge of the pink shape.

Any tips?

[image: Turning circles]

Comment: The length of tangent line from turning circle is difference of travel distance and part of circle between tangent point and initial position of vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exterior boundary of the pink area could be obtained by unwinding tightly a rope previously laid about one of the circles (in order to cope with the fact that we take for a while the curve and then its tangent), and symmetrically for the other. The curve obtained in this way is called a [**circle involute**](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/developpantedecercle/developpantedecercle.shtml) with a classical equation:

$$\begin{cases}x&=&a(\cos(t) + t \sin(t))\\y&=&a(\sin(t) - t \cos(t))\end{cases}$$

when we take the origin in the center of one of the circles.

In fact, we have two arcs of circle involutes that are joined smoothly at the top point of the boundary as can be proven by the given equations.

Remark : an important application of involute of circles is the design of gears.

Edit: here is a Matlab implementation giving the graphic below:

```
for s=-pi/2:pi/12:pi/2; % s = shift value for initial angle 
    t=0:0.01:pi+s;u=t-s; % ranges
    x=1+cos(u)+t.*sin(u);
    y=sin(u)-t.*cos(u)); 
    plot(x,y) % RHS curve
    plot(-x,y); % LHS (mirrored) curve
end;
t=0:0.01:2*pi; % circles:
plot(1+cos(t),sin(t));
plot(-1+cos(t),sin(t));
```

[image]

*Fig. 1: Initial curve in red. The different blue curves that are featured correspond to 12 different shifts from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ with a step $\pi/12$.*

[image]

*Fig. 2: If the range of $s$ is extended to $[-2\pi,2\pi]$ for example, the blue curves are the same as before. One gets good approximations by considering (red curves) involutes based on modified circles with centers in $(\pm 2,0)$ and radius $2$.*

Comment: Thanks - unwinding a rope was just the metaphor in my mind.

Comment: Thanks again +jean-marie. I've tried to reproduce it in a google sheet: https://bit.ly/3CkAJIR
But, it looks long. I think I have the origin of the circle wrong.  Would you be able to help me out a little further please?

Comment: Yes, I am going to write explicitly the equations.

Comment: I'm trying (and failing) to implement it in the linked Google Sheet.  Could we talk privately about me rewarding you for your advice? It won't take a miracle to work out my gmail address from my user name.

Comment: See my Edit. If you have still problems, I agree to communicate via E-mail.

Comment: Thanks Jean - I have just returned to my spreadsheet - and I think I've implemented it correctly.  It looks like your diagram, at least :-)

Spreadsheet here: https://bit.ly/3CkAJIR

I do actually have some extra requirements. In the above example we assume the length of the rope is 1/2 the circumference (pi * r).  But, I would also like to calculate the curve if the rope was a different length.  If it was shorter then we'd leave the circle earlier. If the rope was longer we'd continue further around the circle.

I'm happy to discuss rewarding you for this via email.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I expect we can extend the range of start angles to cover the full extent of the turning circles.  
Follow-on question.   Once the "length of rope" has exceeded the circumference of the turning circle, am I right in thinking that we just add increasingly large "buffer" areas around the outer circle?  So, once the rope is 1m longer than the circumference, we take the ring that represents the full circumference, and push it out 1m.   Does that sound correct?

Comment: Nothing prevents theoretically the start angle $s$ to be in a larger domain that $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$... But what do you mean by "pushing out" the circumference ? I will in a not too long time attempt to produce a second drawing. on which the discussion could take place.

Comment: Please forgive my terminology.  I was suggesting that for any length of rope in excess of the circumference of the turning circle, we would take the Circle Involute for the full circumference of the turning circle, and apply a buffer to the polygon.  Note: buffer on polygon explained here: http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Buffer_(GIS)#Vector_Buffering

Comment: I see: "territorial waters" : in the domain of "mathematical morphology", the equivalent term is "dilation of a shape by a disk".

Comment: @ianmayo see the new figure.

Comment: Each new diagram is more attractive than the previous :-)

Comment: Hello jean-marie - I have a follow on question.  In my implementation I am producing  coordinates as a series of [direction, magnitude] vectors applied to an origin.  Aah, I guess that's a `polar-graphing`. To do this I'm using `atan2` and `pythagoras theorem` to get a vector from the x/y pairs.
I've realised it's much easier to produce the turning circles by just looping through direction values, maintaining the magnitude.
 Is there a `polar graphing` way of producing the circle involute?

Comment: @ianmayo As far as I know, there is no explicit polar equation $r=f(\theta)$ for  circle involutes ($r$ being the distance from origin and $\theta$ the polar angle). One has to build tables... Now, a question: would it be thinkable in your application to switch from continuous "concepts" (no better word comes to my mind) to pixels arrays approaches ?

Comment: Hello Jean-Marie, I need the polar calculation to handle the spherical earth.  If I add x/y coordinates to an origin point they can "warp" as we go further North.  But, if I reverse-calculate the magnitude/direction of the pixel I can apply that to the origin, and the geodesics work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Parametric equations of left part of boundary:

$$x=-r+r\cos t-(l-rt)\sin t$$
$$y=r\sin t+(l-rt)\cos t$$

Here $r$ radius of turning circle, $t$ is angle of turning along circle between going to tangent line, $l$ maximum travel distance, $l-rt$ distance along tangent line.